# controlling column widths for side by side base graphic and ggplot2 graphic

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2

@Ricardo Saporta has proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124373/combine-base-and-ggplot-graphics-in-r-figure-window) an easy way to combine base graphics and ggplot graphics in a multiple plots figure.

I use this way to plot a base graphic at left and a ggplot graphic at right which actually contains two graphics (this is an artifical example, not a real one, but it has the same structure as my real example) :

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(plotrix)

Mvalues <- matrix(rpois(9,1), ncol=3)
Mcolors <- matrix(rpois(9,5), ncol=3)

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
color2D.matplot(x=Mvalues, show.values=2, cellcolors=Mcolors, 
    xlab="x", ylab="y", axes=FALSE, vcex=0.4)
gg2 <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill=cut)) + geom_bar(position="dodge") 
ta <- do.call(arrangeGrob, list(gg2,gg2))
vp.Left <- viewport(height=unit(1, "npc"), width=unit(0.5, "npc"), 
    just="left", y=0.5, x=0.5)
print(ta, vp=vp.Left)
```

[image: plot]

Very nice. But now I want the base graphic to have a larger width than the ggplot graphics. How to do ? I have unsuccessfully tried to do so with the `layout()` function.

Comment: I don't think that there is an easy way to do it. You can play with the vp width and size. otherwise you can see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14231321/make-panels-with-same-margins-when-combining-ggplot-and-base-graphics). but here he implements the first solution of the link that you mentioned.

Comment: @agstudy It's easier than you think. See my answer.

Comment: @Andrie Thank. I miss-understood the problem. I thought he wants the same plot region size. It is easier than I thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

Use layout with different widths. Notice how I define the first column to be double the width of column 2:

```
layout(matrix(c(1, 2, 1, 3), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE), widths=c(2, 1))
```

Set up the graphics

```
layout(matrix(c(1, 2, 1, 3), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE), widths=c(2, 1))
color2D.matplot(x=Mvalues, show.values=2, cellcolors=Mcolors, 
                                xlab="x", ylab="y", axes=FALSE, vcex=0.4)
gg2 <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill=cut)) + geom_bar(position="dodge") 
ta <- do.call(arrangeGrob, list(gg2,gg2))
```

Now define the viewport. Your code was almost there. I simply modified it to be right justified, and changed the width to be 33%:

```
vp <- viewport(height=unit(1, "npc"), width=unit(0.33, "npc"), 
               just="right", x=1, y=0.5)
```

Finally, print the remaining graphic:

```
print(ta, vp=vp)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly the way I tried, but it was unsuccessful. I do not master `layout()` neither `viewport`, surely I did something wrong.

Comment: @Andrie I wonder if you can get the same result using only Layout and keeping the viewport with its defaults arguments?

Comment: Andrie, please I do not understand the matrix argument and the width argument of the `layout()` function. For instance if I want the first column to be 60% of the overall width and the second column to be 40%, what is the matrix and the width to set ?

Comment: The matrix argument only controls the plot order of the graphs, not the widths. Use the widhts argument for the, ahem, widths.

Comment: @Andrie Sorry I have just edited my comment. So I put widths=c(6,4) ?

Comment: Sure, or `widths=c(3, 2)` or `widths=c(60, 40)`, which should all come to the same thing.

Comment: @Andrie Ok thanks that works well. Although the figure is a little outside the window with my real example, but I think I'll find a way to manage.