# R; plotting scatter plot and heat map side by side

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I am trying to create an image showing a scatter plot and a heat map side by side. I create the scatter plot with geom_point and the heatmap with heatmap.2. I then use grid.draw to put them in the same image HOWEVER I cannot get the images to be the same size. How can I make sure they are the same height (this is important as they are ordered the same way and match each other)?

The code I have is:

```
    grab_grob <- function(){
       grid.echo()
       grid.grab()
  }
  g1 <- ggplot(x, aes(x=VIPscore, y=reorder(metabolite, VIPscore))) + geom_point(colour="blue") + labs(y="", x="VIP score")
  heatmap.2(xhm, cexRow=0.5, cexCol=1, Colv=FALSE, Rowv = FALSE, keep.dendro = FALSE, trace="none", key=FALSE, lwid = c(0.5, 0.5), col=heat.colors(ncol(xhm)))  
  g2 <- grab_grob()
  grid.newpage()
  lay <- grid.layout(nrow = 1, ncol=2)
  pushViewport(viewport(layout = lay))
  print(g1,vp=viewport(layout.pos.row = 1, layout.pos.col = 1))
  grid.draw(editGrob(g2, vp=viewport(layout.pos.row = 1, layout.pos.col = 2, clip=TRUE)))
  upViewport(1)
```

I have also tried the geom_tile (instead of heatmap.2) followed by grid.arrange; although the images now match in size colors are awful - they look flat across my data set.

Comment: maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14233531/471093

Comment: Thanks - I have messed around with the code you pointed to but I end up with tiny images on my screen - which part do I change to make image heights taller?

Answer (score 1):

A package called `plotly` might be of help here. Check out their [API docs](https://plot.ly/r/reference/)

```
library(plotly)

df <- data.frame(x = 1:1000,
                 y = rnorm(1000))

p1 <- plot_ly(df, x = x, y = y, mode = "markers") 
p2 <- plot_ly(z = volcano, type = "heatmap")%>% layout(title = "Scatterplot and Heatmap Subplot")

subplot(p1, p2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A drop-in solution could be to use the package "ComplexHeatmap".

https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/ComplexHeatmap/inst/doc/s4.heatmap_annotation.html